# How to publish a JSP project on the Internet using Tomcat web server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I want to publish my JSP project on the Internet from my PC using Tomcat web server. When i run project in localhost everything is ok but when i upload project on server i have trouble

If i visit file index.html everything is ok and i'm sure i have installed Tomcat on server

> But if i visit file ftl all source code is show on screen web page .

I don't understand . Please help me . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ftl` files are Freemarker templates and Tomcat does not support it out of the box. You will need the Freemarker dependency in your project and include instructions in web.xml to map `*.ftl` files to the `freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet` class for processing.

Details are on the [Freemarker web site](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html)

Comment: Oh . I did it . In index.html i have script tag

`<script type="text/javascript">
 location.href="/widget/list.htm?locale=ja_JP";
</script>`
When i visit index.html
error 404 :(

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an archive with the extension *.war* and upload it to the folder `C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps`